I have python and tensorflow installed on my system, but still getting ModuleNotFoundError
I am using windows operating system and have following versions of python and tensorflow, but still my code doesn't work.
python and tensoflow versions
I am getting this error, ModuleNotFoundError.
error that is being generated
Please help me on how to run tensorflow in my system.

Please post the full error stack as text in your question, images are impractical to work with.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\GEU\Projects\13SugarCane_Disease_Detection\sugarcanedisease.py", line 12, in 
import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Do you use a virtual environment (venv) or conda environment?

Yes, I use virtual environment.

You only test outside of the virtual env if you have Tensorflow. Did you install it inside too? With activated virtual env?

Got it, now able to run, Thanks everyone for helping me out!

Mind sharing what was the solution? Was it my comment or something else?
